# Filling in NA values based on other values in the column

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, missing-data

I have a data.table with a large number of missing values. I would like to fill these by adding or subtracting values from the available values in the data.table. In particular, consider this data:

```
> test = data.table(id=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"), x=c(NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA))
> test
    id  x
 1:  A NA
 2:  A NA
 3:  A  0
 4:  A NA
 5:  A NA
 6:  B NA
 7:  B NA
 8:  B  0
 9:  B NA
10:  B NA
```

I need an operation which transforms this into that:

```
    id  x
1:  A -2
2:  A -1
3:  A  0
4:  A  1
5:  A  2
6:  B -2
7:  B -1
8:  B  0
9:  B  1
10: B  2
```

Basically a version of na.locf which increments the last value rather than repeating it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can group by 'id', and take the difference of the row number (`seq_len(.N)`) with the position (`which`) in 'x' where it is 0 (`!x`).  I am wrapping with `as.numeric` as the 'x' column is `numeric` in the input dataset, but from the difference, it is converted to 'integer'.  If there is a clash in `class` while assigning (`:=`), the data.table will show error as it needs matching `class`.

```
test[, x:= as.numeric(seq_len(.N)-which(!x)), id]
test
#    id  x
# 1:  A -2
# 2:  A -1
# 3:  A  0
# 4:  A  1
# 5:  A  2
# 6:  B -2
# 7:  B -1
# 8:  B  0
# 9:  B  1
#10:  B  2
```

`!x` is otherwise written more clearly as `x==0`.  It returns a logical vector of `TRUE/FALSE`.  If there are `NA` values, it will remain as `NA`.  By wrapping with `which`, we get the position of `0` value.  In the example, it is `3` for each 'id'.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much, I've been trying all sorts of combinations of locf and cumsum.

Comment: @phildeutsch  Thanks for the feedback.  Glad to know that it works.

Comment: @akrun I'd like to know why `which(!x)` returns 3?

Comment: @jazzurro Earlier I wrote it `which(x==0)`.  `!x` is basically converting values to TRUE, FALSE for corresponding x values 0, and  all others as FALSE while the NA remains as NA

Comment: @akrun I see. Thanks for that. Starting taking notes again. The revision of your answer is really helpful. :)

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks for your feedback.  Glad to know that it helps

Comment: @akrun You always provide great information for SO users! Thanks again.